# Create custom form in Joomla

Tags: php, joomla1.5, joomla-extensions

I am writing a component for Joomla 1.5. There is a need for a Form in it, infact three forms are needed.

I have searched and looked a lot but could not find where to start so that i should be able to show the form on the front end. The forms will show up in the front end depending upon user information. There will be some difference in each from.

How can i program the form? I know how the components are written, but confused about how forms are integrated in components.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find a good tutorial about creating a Joomla Component http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_Component_-_Part_1

Probably you have to create 3 views for each form.